# Sorting a Javascript Array and get number difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I have 3 Javascript variables with different prices. I need to sort the prices in order of lowest to highest. The item with the lowest price will output "lowest", and the items with the higher price will only show the difference in price.

For example:

```
var apple = 2.99;
var watermelon = 12.99;
var orange = 4.99;
```

This should then output:

```
Apple: Lowest, Orange: $2 more, Watermelon: $10 More
```

To accomplish this, I'm creating an array of three objects.

```
var item = new Array();
item.push({apple:"2.99"});  
item.push({watermelon:"12.99"});    
item.push({orange:"4.99"});
```

Now I need to somehow sort through the array and get the difference in price. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to clean-up the code but this is how you can do what you wanted to achieve.

JSFiddel: http://jsfiddle.net/2a48yLbg/2/

Code:

```
var apple = 2.99;
var watermelon = 12.99;
var orange = 4.99;

var myArray = [{"name":"Oragne", "value":orange}, 
               {"name":"Watermelon", "value":watermelon}, 
               {"name":"Apple", "value":apple}];
myArray.sort(function(a, b){
                return a.value - b.value;
            });

var lowestObject = myArray[0];
var lowestValue = lowestObject.value;
console.log(lowestValue);
var printStatement = "";

for(var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++)
{
    var printObject = myArray[i];
    var partTwo = ""
    if(i === 0)
    { partTwo = "lowest, " } else { partTwo = printObject.value - lowestValue + " more, "};

    printStatement +=  printObject.name + " : " +  partTwo;

}
console.log(printStatement);
document.getElementById ("content").innerHTML = printStatement;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend using objects to associate the names and the prices, because to get the property you will have to use something like `Object.keys(obj)[0]`, which is ugly.

Instead, I suggest storing the data in an array of pairs, e.g. store the name at the first position and the price at the second.

Then, sort the array according to the prices, use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to produce a string for each pair, and finally concatenate the strings.

```
[                                   // Data
  ['Apple', 2.99],
  ['Watermelon', 12.99],
  ['Orange', 4.99]
].sort(function(a,b) {              // Sort by price
  return a[1] - b[1];
}).map(function(pair, index, arr) { // Stringify each pair
  var diff = pair[1] - arr[0][1];
  return pair[0] + ': ' + (diff ? '$' + diff + ' more' : 'Lowest');
}).join(', ');                      // Join the strings
```

Comment: Oh, I'm really missing a declarative `scan` method in JS…

Comment: @Bergi What is a declarative `scan`?

Comment: A mix between `reduce` and `map`, see e.g. [the Haskell one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl). Edit: there's even a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum#Scan_higher_order_function) :-)

Comment: @Oriol 2 Questions: instead of storing the result in a string, is it possible to store the difference back in the original variables? Also, this piece of code goes beyond by Javascript skill and I'm not too sure what to console.log... And THANK YOU for your help!

Comment: @steeped The difference is `diff`. For example, if you want to have triplets [name, price, difference], you can use `pair.push(diff)`. You can `console.log` it all, or you can break it in parts `var data = [...]; data.sort(...); var strings = data.map(...); var string = strings.join()` and place `console.log` between statements.

Comment: @Oriol Any chance of updating your answer so I can see it in action?